# Angular resource, directive issue

Tags: angularjs

I don't quite understand all the glue in Angular for custom directives,

I've made a sample directive here: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZjg6sUgl35GIriaabQg?p=preview

I'm expecting the `ul` list to grow but the `show-card` directive doesn't seem to work. I would expect the `card.value` to be displayed on each `li`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define your directive you have to use camel case, so `<show-card ...>` will have the name `.directive('showCard' ...`, not `.directive('show-card' ...` (see http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: I would also add that `ng-repeat="c in card"` should be on the `li` element as that is the one that is repeating not the `ul`

Comment: Yes, that is probably a mistake as well

Comment: thanks for fixing that mistake, in fact the real question I wanted to ask initially was: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16038891/angular-directive-link-not-called-when-attribute-updates