# Angular directive, link not called when attribute updates

Tags: angularjs

In the following example: http://plnkr.co/edit/OZjg6sUgl35GIriaabQg?p=preview

I've got 2 directives, the `showCard` one inside an ng-repeat which `link` function get called any time the attribute is updated. (see the console)

The other one `showCards` is working properly but the `link` function is not called when the attribute is updated, but only once at the beginning.

I'd like to understand the difference between those 2 kind.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The linking function is only invoked once per element, so whenever you add a new card the ngRepeat-directive will add a new `<show-card ...>` which will invoke the link function.

If you want some function to trigger every time `cards` is changed you can add a $watch function on the scope in the showCards link function, like this:

```
   $scope.$watch('cards',function(){
     console.log('multi',$scope.cards);
   },true);
```

Comment: Thanks - I've been having trouble with an identical problem for ages!